# RealmSwift.Object bool value always false on if condition Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a Realm Object with this structure:

```
class SLevel: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var title: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var notes: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var image: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var updateTime: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var isLock: Bool = true


    @objc dynamic var userLearnedWordsCache: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var totalWordsCache: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var progressCache: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var lockedCache: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var cached: Bool = false


    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id,
        title,
        notes,
        image,
        updateTime,
        isLock
    }

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["userLearnedWordsCache", "totalWordsCache", "progressCache", "lockedCache", "cached"]
    }
}
```

And I have Cellview to build a list of data. everything works fine but when I try to compare .isLock to check a value, this object always returns false. but It show true value on the debugger.

```
 let levelLockState = levels[indexPath.row]
        if levelLockState.isLock { // always return false but data is true
            cell.arrowImg.image = UIImage(named: "ic_lock")

        } else {
            cell.arrowImg.image = UIImage(named: "arrow-right")
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Don't do this `if levelLockState.isLock`, do this `if levelLockState.isLock == true` and it's checking for true.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger does not show correct data in the watch window for managed objects (i.e. those that are obtained from Realm queries) - it will show the default values you assign to the object as in your first code section. This is due to the way that Realm proxy objects work - as defined by the use of `@objc dynamic` in the type declaration. This will always be the case with managed objects.

You can use the `print` command to display the actual data values field-by-field if you wish. In the command window of the debugger (with '(lldb)' prompt to the right of the watch window) type:-

```
print levelLockState.isLock
```

(in the case of your example above) and the result should be correct. This will work as long as you specify value fields, but trying to display another Realm object using this method will give you the same problem again (e.g. `print levelLockState` will give you zeroes and nils again).

As @Jay has determined in his comments below, the debugger will only show correct values when the object has been created locally (i.e. it is not managed).

Comment: it prints true value

Comment: I don'tI agree with this answer, especially this statement *This will always be the case.*. As a test, I have a DogClass Object in my code which has dogName and dogAge properties. I instantiate a new Dog Object with `let dog = DogClass()` followed by `dog.dogName = "Fido"` then `dog.dogAge = 3`. As I step through the code, the watch window updates accordingly as the properties are set. I would certainly be open to more information but I am not finding this answer is correct based on empirical testing. Can  you elaborate?

Comment: @Jay That's interesting, and I'm happy to correct the comment if I'm wrong. I'm speaking from experience that that is how I've always seen the debugger work, but maybe I should specify _from a queried object_, and perhaps your observation is an exception because the object was set in the same code frame and the debugger _watches_ the set action. Also, when you instantiate a new object, is it a _managed_ object when you query the data (i.e. added to the Realm)?

Comment: Some further testing: If the Realm object is created and properties populated (before being written), those properties are properly reflected in the watch window in XCode. However, if an object is queried from Realm, that object shows in the watch window but with its default values (the ones set in the object model). Additionally, even when setting properties within a write, the watch window does not show the updated property value. So the conclusion is the answer is correct for objects that have been previously written to realm, but not for newly created objects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Jay.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad You'll need to show how `levels` is populated and provide some more context.